# Running ASP.NET Core app via Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I've created a new ASP.NET Core app in Visual Studio 2019 (just an API, not Razor), and when I press F5 it opens up a page in the browser at "https://localhost:44357/space/test" which gives a 404 error. The controller is defined like so:

```cs
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SpaceController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("test")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetTestAsync()
        {
            return "Hi";
        }
```

and so I would assume that I'd get back a "Hi" on the page when it goes there.  Why would I be getting back a failure response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your startup class if something is missing, I had success with your example.